# Proguard keepclasseswithmembers: members isnt kept?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have to keep class and members of 2 files: Level and Episode. My proguard.cfg files:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class games.levels.Episode {
public java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> levelLinks;
public java.util.ArrayList<Level> levels;
public java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> skin;
public int id;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class games.levels.Level {
public int id;
public int episode;
public int numEnemies;
}
```

And my proguards mapping.txt file:

```
games.levels.Level -> games.levels.Level:
    int id -> id
    int episode -> episode
    int numEnemies -> numEnemies
games.levels.Episode -> games.levels.a:
    java.util.ArrayList levelLinks -> a
    java.util.ArrayList levels -> b
    java.util.ArrayList skin -> c
    int id -> d
```

I just can't understand what happens here. Could anyone please help me some traces why Level work, but not with Episode? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED AT LAST!
If you wanna keep names of all members of a class, just use  wildcard=> it means matching any fields:

```
-keep class X.Y.Z {
    <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a strange proguard setup. Normally `-keepclasseswithmembers` is meant to cover a range of classes that all have matching members, not keeping specific classes by matching the members.

I suggest using:

`-keep class games.levels.Episode
-keep class games.levels.Level`

This will keep your classes intact without trying to force a match on the members as well as the specific class names.

The problem here is that the Episode class is not being matched due to the members defined in your proguard config not matching the actual members of your Episode class.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't "keep" option just keep class name? I need to load 2 classes from json by java reflecion(String), hence their's properties' name can't be changed. For members' name, I just copy from my source file :(.

Comment: Ok, I change to 'keep' found that the problem only happens with custom class like ArrayList or own defined classes. What should i do now, pls?

Comment: Are you working with gson or jackson? If so, you may want to look into -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,InnerClasses,Signature as well